# c# dataGridView cellLeave event not firing

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having a DataGridView and want to update a label with the SUM of the rows as I enter values in that specific column(row by row). Its basically an invoice generation gridView. I need to keep updating the total amount label as I enter item price into the gridview. I am trying to use cellLeave event because I want the amount to be updated as soon as I leave the cell and come to the next row. But the event is not firing.. Really need help on this! 
I am using this code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
    {
        Double result = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            result += Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[2].Value);
        }

        this.label3.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Event is not firing or your code is not working?

Comment: Event is not firing.. I mean if I enter values, the Label is not updated.

Comment: Enter values __and__ leave the cell ? Event hooked up?

Comment: Did you tried putting messagebox or breakpoint?

Comment: @TaW: Yeah enter values and leave the cell. Event hooked up means?

Comment: @Anurag: I didnt tried putting any of them..

Comment: To 'hook up an event' means that the handler must be attached. Either (& best) do it in the propertes- events-tab (the one with the arrow) and enter the event ('dataGridView1_CellLeave') at the right slot or do it in code: `dataGridView1.CellLeave +=dataGridView1_CellLeave;` in the form constructor.

Answer (score 0):

That event should be captured on the client side. Try to AJAXify the control and then manage the logic.

Comment: This is a Winforms question.

Comment: Oh, I mistook it for the web counterpart. My bad